# Как задать верхний уровень разделов документа

Tags: latex

Пишу маленький документ по шаблону 'Article'. Однако ни разделов, ни секций в нём нет. Самая верхняя единица структуры документа - *\subsection{Особенности}*. Документ собирается, но когда я гляжу получившийся pdf, то вижу заголовок:

**0.1 Особенности**

Как бы убрать лидирующий "0" в нумерации ?  Вставил:

```
\settocdepth{subsection}
```

Но не помогает.

Comment: Команда `\settocdepth{subsection}` для оглавлений - задает самый мелкий уровень, который попадет в оглавление, т.е. все более мелкие не попадут. В Вашем случае, в оглавление попали бы разделы (при наличии, конечно): `part`, `chapter`, `section` и `subsection`.

Comment: @Vladimir Это я постиг на практике :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого достаточно переопределить команду вывода значения счетчика `\thesubsection`:
`\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\subsection{первый}
text text text

\subsection{второй}
text text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло :-)